# 18.04 "No Wifi Adapter Found" ASUS TUF FX505DU Wireless Connection Issues

Tags: 18.04, wireless, asus

I've been using all the methods I could already find online, and I've now come to understand that there is no driver that is claiming my laptop's network card

Here are my outputs from Linux:

**iwconfig**

`enp2s0    no wireless extensions.
 lo        no wireless extensions.`

**lshw -C network**

```
  *-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: enp2s0
   version: 15
   serial: 04:d4:c4:77:53:f3
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.045.08-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.0.3 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:52 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7804000-f7804fff memory:f7800000-f7803fff
*-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Network controller
   product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7600000-f760ffff
```

**sudo lspci**

```
"04:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device c822"
```

**lspci -knn | grep Net -A3**

`04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:c822]
    Subsystem: AzureWave Device [1a3b:3750]
    Kernel modules: wl
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Picasso [1002:15d8] (rev c2)`

**lsusb**

`Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 13d3:56a2 IMC Networks 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 13d3:3548 IMC Networks 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`

Seems fishy to me here, but I don't know for sure. Normally wouldn't Realtek show in at least one of the devices for **lsusb**? Or maybe not because it is an integrated wireless adapter in this laptop.

**uname -r**

```
4.15.0-54-generic
```

I next tried to build from the Realtek site [using this link here.](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software) I built the **GBE** file because it says that it goes up to a 4.15 kernel.

The build was fine, and r8168 seems to work because **lsmod | grep r8168** returns:

```
r8168                 524288  0
```

I have been told that if you get an output, you did the configuration correctly. I also edited the blacklist.conf and added `blacklist r8169` and rebooted my system, to no effect.

Comment: That device looks to be supported in the 5.2 kernels

Comment: Are you having a problem with your wireless, or ethernet? Your title says wireless, but then you talk about installing a r8168 driver for ethernet. Is this a Desktop or Server installation? Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`.

Answer (score 0):

Try Installing new kernel 5 by command:

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
```

It work for me.

Comment: Which device "worked for you"? `b822 or c822`? You post this answer to all of them.